# SSRS reports - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting the following message when trying to access the calendar control in SSRS report viewer. The user is able to type the date.

*The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'*

[image: screenshot]

This happened after a recent release. Any help is appreciated.